# How to refit a model on multiple train sets, without changing the hyperparameters fit with RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I find the best hyperparameters for a model using `RandomizedSearchCV`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from scipy.stats import uniform
iris = load_iris()
logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='saga', tol=1e-2, max_iter=200, random_state=0)
distributions = dict(C=uniform(loc=0, scale=4), penalty=['l2', 'l1'])
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(logistic, distributions, random_state=0)
model = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Now I want to refit the same model to different datasets (having of course the same input and output features) *keeping all hyperparameters fixed*: the model weights instead change, because of the refitting. How can I do that? I don't think using the `fit` method of `model` would work, because that's the `fit` method of a `RandomizedSearchCV` object, thus it would refit the hyperparameters too...

Comment: Couldn't you use `RandomizedSearchCV`'s attributes `best_...` to create the appropriate `LogisticRegression` and then fit that?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I don't understand what you mean. Why don't you write an answer? You have all the code you need to write one. If you need a different dataset on which to retrain the model (**without touching the hyperparameters!!!**),  just create a random one with the same columns of iris, or fuse the train and test iris sets together, whatever you find easier.

Comment: I asked a question because I assume, but I'm not sure, that you want the _best_ `C` and `penalty` values from `RandomizedSearchCV.fit`.  And then you want to use those values in new `LogisticRegression.fit` with new datasets, yes?

Comment: @rickhg12hs that's a way, yes. I see also a `best_estimator_` attribute. I wonder if that could be a more direct way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Yes, believe so.  When you try it, does it perform well?